# ASP .NET Core 2.1-preview2 HttpClient deadlock

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have ASP.NET Core 2.1 application hosted on Azure web app. I am sending photos base64 string over WebSockets and then by HttpClient to Azure Face API.

After some 150-250 requests HttpClient stops responding and I can't use HttpClient class in any part of my application.

In my localhost it works properly and I never get this problem.

```
public class FaceApiHttpClient
{
    private HttpClient _client;

    public FaceApiHttpClient(HttpClient client)
    {
        _client = client;
    }

    public async Task<string> GetStringAsync(byte[] byteData,string uri)
    { 
        using (ByteArrayContent content = new ByteArrayContent(byteData))
        {
            content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

            HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.PostAsync(uri, content).ConfigureAwait(false);

            return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

    }
}
```

**DI:**

```
         services.AddHttpClient<FaceApiHttpClient>(
            client => {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("xxx");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "xxx");
            });
```

The method from FaceApiClient is invoke in a Scoped Service:

```
public interface IFaceAPIService
{
    Task<DataServiceResult<List<Face>>> GetFacesDataFromImage(byte[] byteArray);
}

public class FaceAPIService: ServiceBase, IFaceAPIService
{
    private readonly IServerLogger _serverLogger;
    private FaceApiHttpClient _httpClient;
    //Consts
    public const string _APIKey = "xxx";
    public const string _BaseURL = "xxx";

    public FaceAPIService(IServerLogger serverLogger, FaceApiHttpClient client)
    {
        _serverLogger = serverLogger;
        _httpClient = client;          
    }

    public async Task<DataServiceResult<List<Face>>> GetFacesDataFromImage(byte[] byteData)
    {
        try
        {
            // Request parameters. A third optional parameter is "details".
            string requestParameters = "returnFaceId=true&returnFaceLandmarks=false&returnFaceAttributes=age,gender,headPose,smile,facialHair,glasses,emotion,hair,makeup,occlusion,accessories,blur,exposure,noise";

            // Assemble the URI for the REST API Call.
            string uri = _BaseURL + "/detect" + "?" + requestParameters;
            var result = await _httpClient.GetStringAsync(byteData, uri).ConfigureAwait(false);
            List<Face> faces = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Face>>(result);
            return Success(faces);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _serverLogger.LogExceptionFromService(ex);
            return DataServiceResult.ErrorResult<List<Face>>(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

a) on localhost enviroment it works. I run 11 simulators with many request per seconds and it never broke (10 hours of simulators, over 20k requests).

b) HttpClient stops working in any part of application not only in one class.

How to fix this?

Comment: How is `HttpClient` registered with the service collection? creating too many instances of `HttpClient` is not advised.

Comment: It is added by services.AddHttpClient in Startup.cs class

Comment: I don't know if it is the root of the problem, but when using a shared client instance you should not repeatedly add DefaultRequestHeaders. In fact, you should not add headers that way at all unless all requests will require the same ones.

Comment: @Crowcoder I changed this and start testing. I will let you know soon if this help.

Comment: Still the same problem. I need to restart my app to get it work.

Comment: How is `FaceApiHttpClient.GetStringAsync` being invoked?

Comment: I made edit in my post. Strange thing is that in localhost it works on 20k+ request, 10 hours testing with no deadlock.

Comment: Deadlock implies concurrency issue, but I don't think that's the case for you. It sounds more like you are running out of sockets. Where are you hosting it on? Azure? Which tier? They often have limit on the number of sockets that they can have open, depending on the VM/plans tier

Comment: Azure App Service (Standard: 1 Small). Socekts you mean WebSockets? I Tested the same number of request from WebSockets without httpClient call and it works properly.

Comment: You are not disposing your `HttpResponseMessage response`. That might be the reason, but even if not - worth doing that anyway.

Comment: @Evk thanks for your suggestion. I will apply this and let you know if it works after testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After release version of **ASP .NET CORE 2.1 RC1** the problem is fixed. I updated project to new version and now there is no problem with deadlock.

The problem with deadlock was only in **ASP .NET CORE 2.1 Preview 2** version.

Answer (score 2):

Consider changing up the design a bit.

Using a typed client the assumption is that its configuration is something that will not change frequently and that it should be added once when registering the typed client.

```
services.AddHttpClient<FaceApiHttpClient>(_ => {
    _.BaseAddress = new Uri(Configuration["OcpApimBaseURL"]);
    var apiKey = Configuration["OcpApimSubscriptionKey"];
    _.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", apiKey);
    _.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);
});
```

Which would allow the typed client to no have to add the key for every call

```
public class FaceApiHttpClient {
    private readonly HttpClient client;

    public FaceApiHttpClient(HttpClient client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

    public async Task<string> GetStringAsync(byte[] byteData, string uri) {            
        using (var content = new ByteArrayContent(byteData)) {
            // This example uses content type "application/octet-stream".
            // The other content types you can use are "application/json" and "multipart/form-data".
            content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

            // Execute the REST API call.
            HttpResponseMessage response;  response = await _client.PostAsync(uri, content).ConfigureAwait(false);

            // Get the JSON response.
            return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
}
```

It should be noted from [ASP.NET Core 2.1-preview1: Introducing HTTPClient factory](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/02/28/asp-net-core-2-1-preview1-introducing-httpclient-factory/)

> A typed client is, effectively, a transient service, meaning that a new instance is created each time one is needed and it will receive a new HttpClient instance each time it is constructed. This means that the configuration func, in this case retrieving the URI from configuration, will run every time something needs a `FaceApiHttpClient`.

Based on previous documentations, having that many clients created can pose problems, but the assumption here is that the developers of this new feature took that into consideration when designing it.

I say this because the issues you described are similar to previous problem with the same cause.

Comment: I made test with your suggestions and it still not working. Deadlock after 50 requests. On localhost 20k+ requests without deadlock.

Comment: @NorbertPisz, I think you are most likely running out of sockets. To test this theory, try reverting back to the previous way of using `HttpClient`. Create a singleton `HttpClient` and use just the one in the `FaceApiHttpClient`. Test and see if the same issue occurs. Could be that the preview framework is not ready as yet.

Comment: No I will test 2 ways: a) I add HttpClient as singleton b) I will use one instance of HttpClient in my WebSockets singleton class. I will let you know about result. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any idea how to get detailed error on this deadlock?

Comment: @NorbertPisz have a look at this article to understand why we think it is a socket issue https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/

Comment: My suspicion is that the Azur Web app drastically limits the available sockets while on your localhost does not have that limitation.

Comment: I think that you found problem source. But the solution is to make HttpClient static?

Comment: @NorbertPisz Did you find a good solution for this? I'm having the same problem... worked fine under Preview1, works fine locally under Preview2, and fails spectacularly in an Azure App Service.

Comment: @Scott no I didn't solve this. But my app running 2 weeks in Production. Now I have only 8 IOT devices connected and there no more than 10 requests per minute. This error happens only when is over 30 requests per second. Try to change your app service plan to highest and let me know if it help you.

Comment: @Scott do you have any fix? Still have deadlock one per some numer of request (5 days)

Comment: I don't have any fix. I've created a dummy Web API to test against instead of the production service I'm using; my web app behaved properly for longer than I had seen with the real endpoint. Still confused. Hard to believe there's a problem with HttpClient in Preview 2, but I wonder what's going on.

Comment: @Scott after 16 hours of many tries I stop it... Maybe we should wait for new version 2.1 RC. New version will be avaiable in Azure App in few days. I have my application updated to new version and I'm waiting for Azure Update. I will let you now if this helps me.
Interesting thing is that I have also other application on Asp .net core 1 and there is any problems with HttpClient...

Comment: I've upgraded to ASP.NET Core 2.1 RC1, deployed it as a self-contained application (i.e. I deploy the version of the framework with the app) to Azure App Service, and, so far, I haven't had this problem again. Must have been some weirdness in Preview2, or in the extension in App Service for Preview2.

I'll switch back to a framework-dependent deployment (expecting the framework to be on the machine) when App Service rolls out RC1. Much smaller deployment footprint, of course.